# Fixing OpenStreetMap scale in MapInfo?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapinfo, scale

I have OpenStreetMap (OSM) in MapInfo and I would like to export a County but when I zoom out to view the county the map scale changes.

Does anyone know how to set the scale of OSM so I can export it at higher level of detail for a greater geographic area?

Answer (score 2):

A [tiled web map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map) provides just a series of tile bitmaps at fixed zoom levels.

I am not aware of any tile server that allows to client to customize its rendering styles.
You could try some different tile server that is configured to render more details at a specific scale, or implement your own tile server.
But as long as you're using the same server, the only way to increase the level of detail is to increase the resolution, i.e., to use a bigger monitor (and then the text labels will appear smaller).

(This is how all tile servers work; it is not specific to either OSM or MapInfo.)

Comment: You could "start from the other end", I guess - [kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik) is designed for developing map styles, but does actually incorporate a local tile server.  You could use that to tweak the zoom levels used in your map style to achieve the desired result.  If you do that, I guess you'll then be able to see the results in Mapinfo, but you may be able to do that with Mapinfo too?